# Lua - Syntax error in if-statement

Tags: syntax, lua

Just tried to execute a small Lua script, but unfortunately I'm doing something wrong. I've no more ideas what the fault might be.

```
function checkPrime( n )
    for i = 2, n-1, 1 do
        if n % i == 0 then
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

The interpreter says:

```
lua: /home/sebastian/luatest/test.lua:3: `then' expected near `%'
```

I think it's not a big thing and perhaps it's quite clear what is wrong. But somehow I cannot see it at the moment.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it is perfectly enough to check roots up to math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) instad of n-1, when you want to check if a number is prime or not.

Comment: That's right, but I use the script only to measure execution times of different scripting languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is probably some version problem, check your version of lua.  The usage of '%' as an infix operator for modulo can only be used in Lua 5.1, in 5.0 it is not supported yet.  Try using `math.mod` instead:

```
if math.mod(n,i) == 0 then
```

**Edit**: Also note that in 5.1, `math.mod` still exists, but it has been renamed to `math.fmod`. For now, the old name still works, but support will probably be removed in future versions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping "n% i == 0" in parentheses? Stupid question, but sometimes overlooked!

Comment: In parentheses? But then it is a string. As I see it, LUA does not eval it or so...

Comment: No, lua does not require parentheses around the expression, since 'if' and 'then' perfectly delimit it.

Comment: This is a perfect solution as it causes lua to process the entire expression as a single boolean (and thus avoids the cryptic error message). BTW, it doesn't turn into a string if you do that...